# How to reinstall the Crashlytics Beta profile on a device

Tags: crashlytics-beta

The crashlytics beta profile was deleted from a device I use to test iOS enterprise apps with.  I can't figure out how to get the profile back on the device.  The documentations says to use the email where the device is being invited, but this app is 5 years old and that email is long gone.  How do I get this device back on the Crashlytics Beta radar?